# На PHP как то можно поместить функции в очередь?

Tags: php

Идея сложить несколько методов в очередь и вызвать их когда очередь обработается

В общем есть пачка методов например 500 штук, нужно вызывать их в определенной последовательности пока не будет найден результат

например

```
class Test{
public function m1{};
public function m2{};
public function m3{};
}

$test = new Test();

$arr[] = &$test->m1();
$arr[] = &$test->m2();
$arr[] = &$test->m3();

foreach($arr as $m){
if($r = $m()){
break;
return;
}
}
```

Или как то так

```
while(($r = $arr->next()()) != NULL){

}
```

Comment: А php разве не так работает? Он по очереди будет выполнять методы из списка, или я что-то не так понял, не совсем понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan в массив можно поместить строки потом пройти по нему и выполнить методы по строкам, но я думал можно ли как то ссылку на сам метод поместить в массив хотя бы

Comment: Пример лучше покажите, примерно понял, но в угадайку играть времени нет

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php Пример #4 Сallable-фукнции

Comment: @Visman об этом я писал, выше

Comment: Посуте напоминает https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern. Но под капотом всёравно массив со списком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A{
    public function a1(){
        echo "a1";
    }
    public function a2(){
        echo "a2";
    }
    public function a3(){
        echo "a3";
    }
}

$a = new A();
$arr = ['a1','a3','a2'];
foreach ($arr as $method){
    $a->$method();
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc591eb715f090b300c228a923fa861d8ed1d22a)

Comment: это единственный вариант? я о нем писал в комментарии, могу предложить ещё наследование и вызов parent метода, и переопределение в наследнике, но менее гибкий способ

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich нет, это не единственный вариант. Чем он вас не устраивает?

Comment: В принципе устраивает, просто надеялся кто то какой то паттерн предложит

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich я слабо себе представляю, какой паттерн можно натянуть на итерацию по массиву. Если прям совсем зудит применить какой нибудь шаблон проектирования, то организуйте класс `Queue` и наполните его объектами, реализующими паттерт "Команда". А потом так же в цикле его примените.

Comment: спасибо попробую